# How to make an SVG <image> element clickable in FireFox

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I am having a difficult time getting an svg  element to be clickable.

Everything works correctly in Chrome but in FireFox 64.0.2 the element has no cursor and is not clickable.

The svg image is inside a JQuery.Sticky div tag, with 100% width, in which I have to set pointer-event: none so does not make items under the div unclickable.  The SVG file is lazy loaded. This button image within the div does need to be clickable.

I have set svg image element with: inline style="pointer-events: all;" 
I have also tried to set the same via a an class ".roomopenico" which has the same.
I have also tried to add the class using query: $("#TreasureChest_Open").css("pointer-events", "all");  ($.addClass does not work on svg elements)

Everything works correctly in Chrome but not in FireFox 64.0.2. In FF the element is visible but has no cursor and is not clickable. Is this a FireFox bug or have I done something wrong?

This is my sticky div containing a button that uses an SVG image:

```
<div id="DailyBonusMagnetWrapper" class="c" style="padding: 4px; width: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
    <button id="btn_dailybonusmagnet" style="background: transparent; border: 0; height: auto; width: 100%; display: block; margin-left: -10px;" title="6-Hour Bonus">
        <div id="db_box_open" class="c divlazymg">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
                <image id="TreasureChest_Open" class="roomopenico" style="pointer-events: all;" width="113" height="130" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KG....TOO LONG TO INCLUDE HERE...5sAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old relic from HTML4 era where it was "sort of the expected behavior" to ignore pointer-events on HTMLButtonElement's children.
Firefox, since the beginning sticked to this rule.

So to avoid this, the solution is to wrap your elements in something else than a `<button>`:

```html
<div id="DailyBonusMagnetWrapper" class="c" style="padding: 4px; width: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
    <!-- replaced <button> by a <div>-->
    <div id="btn_dailybonusmagnet" style="background: transparent; border: 0; height: auto; width: 100%; display: block; margin-left: -10px;" title="6-Hour Bonus">
        <div id="db_box_open" class="c divlazymg">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
                <image id="TreasureChest_Open" class="roomopenico" style="pointer-events: all; cursor:pointer" width="113" height="130" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But note that the upcoming Firefox 66 will now behave like other vendors, by not blocking the event on the parent <button>. You can already try this from the  Nightly branch. [[issue-report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1089326)]

Comment: Thanks so much. This fixed my problem and saved me a lot of time and frustration.